# Android: thread exiting with uncaught exception

Tags: java, android

I have got problem and I can't find a solution for it. When I receive data over Bluetooth connection, my program suddenly crashes. I am receiving data in separate thread where is each received byte saved in queue.
 I also have one TimerTask, which calls method for read data from queue every 1 ms, and refresh TextBox in UI. My program works for a while, but then suddenly crashes. Please help. Here are the main code snippets.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{       
    TextView myLabel1;
    volatile boolean stopWorker = false;


    public Queue<Byte> receiverQueue = new LinkedList<Byte>();
    protected byte[] receiverArray;
    private boolean newDataRead = false;

    //timer
    TimerTask mTimerTask;
    Timer timer = new Timer();  
    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

myLabel1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//start with timer ticking after 1 sec, and give timer tick every 1ms

onTimerTick();
timer.schedule(mTimerTask, 1000, 1); 
}


//method for reading data from receiverQueue
protected void readDataFromReceiverBuffer() {
    //if receiverQueue is not empty, read data
    if(receiverQueue.isEmpty() == false) {
        //declaration of byte array receiverField size of receiverQueue
        receiverArray = new byte[receiverQueue.size()];
        //read bytes from queue until is empty
            for (int i = 0; receiverQueue.isEmpty() == false; i++) {
                //retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null 
            receiverArray[i] = receiverQueue.poll();
            }
        //variable newData is set to true, when we read new data from queue
        newDataRead = true;
    }
}       


Thread dataReceiveThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    //received byte
    int receivedData;
    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {

            try { 
                //read one byte from InputStream
                receivedData = mmInStream.read();
                //inserts received byte into this queue if it is possible 
                if(receivedData != -1)
                    receiverQueue.offer((byte)receivedData);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                stopWorker = true;
            }           
            //Log.i(String.valueOf(receivedData), "valueOfReceivedData");
        }           
    }       
}); 

public void onTimerTick() {
mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    String temp;
    //this method is called 
        public void run() {
            //call method for read data from queue
            readDataFromReceiverBuffer();
            timerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //when new data has arrived, we update UI 
                if(newDataRead == true) {
                    //convert byte array to string
                    temp = new String(receiverArray, 0, receiverArray.length);
                     myLabel1.setText(temp);
                     newDataRead = false;
                }                               
                    }
                }); 
      }};    
}
```

LogCat:

```
W/dalvikvm(12358): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab1210)
E/AndroidRuntime(12358): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
E/AndroidRuntime(12358): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=21; index=21
E/AndroidRuntime(12358):    at com.example.colibri2bb.MainActivity.readDataFromReceiverBuffer(MainActivity.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(12358):    at com.example.colibri2bb.MainActivity.readDataFromReceiverBuffer(MainActivity.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(12358):    at com.example.colibri2bb.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(12358):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

LogCat:

```
W/dalvikvm(17344): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab1210)
E/AndroidRuntime(17344): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
E/AndroidRuntime(17344): java.util.NoSuchElementException
E/AndroidRuntime(17344): atjava.util.LinkedList.removeFirstImpl(LinkedList.java:689)
E/AndroidRuntime(17344): at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:676)
E/AndroidRuntime(17344): at java.util.LinkedList.poll(LinkedList.java:895)
E/AndroidRuntime(17344):atcom.example.colibri2bb.MainActivity.readDataFromReceiverBuffer(MainActivity.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(17344): atcom.example.colibri2bb.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime(17344): at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: The variable newDataRead should have been declared as volatile.

Comment: receiverArray[i] = receiverQueue.poll();

Comment: well, it seems that `receiverQueue.isEmpty() == true` but `receiverArray` is one space smaller then i as you can see from your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could some other thread be modifying the receiverQueue and adding data while you're reading from it?
Try using this for loop instead. It should make sure you don't go out of bounds.

```
int queueSize = receiverQueue.size();
receiverArray = new byte[queueSize ];
for (int i = 0; i<queueSize; i++) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume that this could be the reason. This works now, but I get another error. I post new LogCat. Like @njzk2 said, this could happened because of too long task?

Comment: Now it seems that the queue has less elements than it had originally... You could try both conditions in the for loop (queue is not empty, and i < size). But these are all small fixes, you have a larger problem of several threads updating the same object. You need to synchronize all these threads.

Comment: Could you please suggest me what is the best way to synchronize all threads? I'm noob at object programming and don't have much experinece..

Comment: Java concurrency is a big subject. The simplest way would be to make all functions that modify this object 'synchronized' (public synchronized void readDataFromReceiveBuffer()...) - but all the functions that access this object must be synchronized, not just some. See this guide for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check this guide. But in my case, onTimerTick() is the only method which invokes readDataFromReceiveBuffer(). I think in my case is a problem, that timer ticks to fast, and when readDataFromBuffer() is still executing, it's called again from onTimerTick() - then crashes...

Comment: There must be some method that puts data in the queue too, right?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the Exception type that is being thrown is not IOException. Catch all exceptions and see - change IOException to Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem goes here: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=21; index=21 MainActivity.readDataFromReceiverBuffer`.
You try to assign value to `receiverArray[21]`  when your array only contains 21 elements!

Answer (score 0):

your receiverArray is initialized with the size of the queue, but then the queue expands while you read it, and you end up with more data than you expected.

You have to make sure you are not reading too much, most likely by testing the index against the size (the extra data would be read at the next execution of `readDataFromReceiverBuffer`)

You could also assign a much larger array (but testing is still mandatory)

Your second issue could be about your task to be too long, and therefore some overlaping and concurrent access to the queue. (basically, 2 instances test if the queue is empty, both try to read from it, but there is only one element)

I would use a thread with a loop, a time measurement of the loop execution, and a sleep for delaying until the next required execution, rather than a timer. That would ensure single access to reading the queue.